# Load Url within the WebView Onclick Android

Tags: android

How Do i open a Specific URL in my WebView on button click? i have tried this code but it opens the URL in the Default browser, i want it to open the URL in the same WebView

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) { 
Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
startActivity(myWebLink);
 }
```

i have tried this one also, it works fine! but it prompts me to pick one application and when i press back button, it works

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) { 
Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
startActivity(myWebLink);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This Works for me

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) { 
Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  myWebLink.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

and after this use

```
 myWebLink.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

And if you want to open url using Intent
Try this

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"); 
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

For same webview you need webview client for open in same webview.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are both losing the URL in your WebView and opening the browser app. The *Intent* Object you are using is meant for passing data between Activities, which is the cause of your trouble. You do not want to use this. Instead, remove all code other than

mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

This will show Google in your web view.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **webview.setWebViewClient()**

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl)
    {
    }
});
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```